# Copy selection but increase numbers in it by one

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, shortcut

I find myself having to repeat a trivial task a lot.

**The task is:**

> Copy pasting a section (a comment, css line, html line etc.) and having to increase the number in that section for each time I paste it

**Example:**

I want to repeat the following comment 7 times but have the number increase for each repetition.

```
/* ===================================
   ============ SECTION 1 ============
   =================================== */
```

---

> **GOAL:** I hope that someone know of a function/shortcut in intelji, perhaps similiar to that of excel?:
>   [Watch GIF](https://gyazo.com/349a7163b417e9364c06f4dfa21c5441). An alternative solution to any of the ones listed below would be appreciated too!

---

I got a **few solutions**: (However I would like to know if there is any faster way of doing it)

1. Doing it manually
2. Using a small JavaScript script

```
    const Enter_string = (s, number_of_copies) => {
        console.log(s);
        let copy = s;

        for (let i=0; i<number_of_copies; i++) {
            copy = copy.replace(/(\d+)/, (fullMatch, n) => {return `${Number(n) + 1}`});
            console.log(copy);
        }
    };

    Enter_string('/* ===================================\n' +
            '============ SECTION 1 ============\n' +
            '=================================== */\n',
            2);
```

3. If the case permits, using Excel.
4. > **Can it be done using any Intelij shortcut?**

Comment: The only increment/decrement thing is in https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation

Comment: @Meo Yes, this is what I have been looking for: [Screenshot of highlighted text](https://gyazo.com/e93468233c0b8bc1225d69b92dfdb6b4)